# Lets Encrypt does not sign my domains

Tags: ssl, debian, plesk, lets-encrypt

I'm running plesk 17 on a debian machine. One certificate could be signed without problems. But then I got this error:

```
Error: Let's Encrypt SSL certificate installation failed: Failed letsencrypt execution: Saving debug log to /opt/psa/var/modules/letsencrypt/logs/letsencrypt.log
Starting new HTTPS connection (1): acme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org
Obtaining a new certificate
Performing the following challenges:
http-01 challenge for mindmailer.de
http-01 challenge for www.mindmailer.de
Starting new HTTPS connection (1): 127.0.0.1
Waiting for verification...
Cleaning up challenges
Failed authorization procedure. mindmailer.de (http-01): urn:acme:error:unauthorized :: The client lacks sufficient authorization :: Invalid response from http://mindmailer.de/.well-known/acme-challenge/Zg70UTECV4lP-E25ateUev3vsq5nCbX-4L-KUXwUU4I: &quot;&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;
&lt;html lang=&quot;de&quot; xmlns=&quot;http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml&quot;&gt;
&lt;head&gt;

&lt;meta charset=&quot;utf-8&quot;&gt;
&lt;!--
This website is powe&quot;, www.mindmailer.de (http-01): urn:acme:error:unauthorized :: The client lacks sufficient authorization :: Invalid response from http://www.mindmailer.de/.well-known/acme-challenge/rreVCbEY8pX5eaWVMGiZsg2UxNennZfwkHC6WMAJV-Q: &quot;&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;
&lt;html lang=&quot;de&quot; xmlns=&quot;http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml&quot;&gt;
&lt;head&gt;

&lt;meta charset=&quot;utf-8&quot;&gt;
&lt;!--
This website is powe&quot;
IMPORTANT NOTES:
- The following errors were reported by the server:

Domain: mindmailer.de
Type: unauthorized
Detail: Invalid response from
http://mindmailer.de/.well-known/acme-challenge/Zg70UTECV4lP-E25ateUev3vsq5nCbX-4L-KUXwUU4I:
&quot;&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;
&lt;html lang=&quot;de&quot; xmlns=&quot;http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml&quot;&gt;
&lt;head&gt;

&lt;meta charset=&quot;utf-8&quot;&gt;
&lt;!--
This website is powe&quot;

Domain: www.mindmailer.de
Type: unauthorized
Detail: Invalid response from
http://www.mindmailer.de/.well-known/acme-challenge/rreVCbEY8pX5eaWVMGiZsg2UxNennZfwkHC6WMAJV-Q:
&quot;&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;
&lt;html lang=&quot;de&quot; xmlns=&quot;http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml&quot;&gt;
&lt;head&gt;

&lt;meta charset=&quot;utf-8&quot;&gt;
&lt;!--
This website is powe&quot;

To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
entered correctly and the DNS A record(s) for that domain
contain(s) the right IP address.
```

What could be the problem in this case? 
DNS A records are on the right ip adress .. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have redirects, which conflicts with the Let's Encrypt - challenge ( => "marketing.mindmailer.de" ) and as you can see in your error - log, Let's Encrypt tries to write to "mindmailer.de/.well-known/acme-challenge/", which is not possible this way.